# Is there a continuum between analogous and homologous traits?

Tags: evolution, homology

How closely-related do two species need to be for a trait they share (say, bipedalism in mammals) to count as homologous (divergently-evolved) as opposed to analogous (convergently-evolved)?

In other words, is there a sharp dichotomy between analogous vs homologous traits (and if so, how is the cut-off criterion defined)? Or is there a continuum among them, and if so, again, on what bases is this defined?

Does said trait need to maybe "skip" a given number of intervening species on the tree of life for it to count as convergently evolved (in the example above: there being many mammals species in between humans and kangaroos, both bipedal)? Or is this somehow all about (continuously expressed) phylogenetic distance? Googling/chatGPTing didn’t really enlight me, hence this question.

Comment: The wings of bats and the wings of birds are analogous; their shared ancestor had no wings, their other close relatives have no wings, etc. They are quite different in form and structure despite each being used for flight. But, they also both evolved from homologous vertebrate forelimbs. Their common ancestor has forelimbs, all of their close relatives have forelimbs, etc. Is this the sort of thing you're asking about?

Comment: It is, but since it is a rather classical example of convergent evolution, I'm still not clear I understand what is the hard criterion that enables one to classify a trait as being homologous OR analogous between two species in more border-line cases where perhaps less is known about whether the LCA shared that trait or not.

Comment: I think the "close relatives" (as you note above) having or not having that trait gets us closer to the answer I was looking for, as it essentially invokes philogenetic distance, although, again, it's unclear just how many related species one has to count.

Comment: If nothing is known about the common ancestor I don't think anyone would bother claiming a trait as homologous or analogous, but you can often infer things about the common ancestor from just two species you are looking at plus a member of an outgroup. If, for example, some mutation conferring a different function of a protein is present in two species and absent in an outgroup species that doesn't have that trait or mutation, you'd infer it's more likely that the common ancestor of those two species also had the mutation rather than the identical mutation happening twice.

Comment: Do you have some specific example to consider?

Comment: One example I had in mind (though maybe not the best) was the one mentioned in the question: bipedalism. One can find this trait in animals closely related to humans (e.g. other great apes; and thus argue it to be homologous in the context of that comparison); but one can also encounter it in distantly related animals, and thus argue it to be analogous. Am I making sense? (I'm no evolutionary biologist - and it shows!)

Comment: In that example I think you'd say that bipedalism (to the extent that other great apes are bipedal; some would argue they are not even if they occasionally go up on two limbs) is homologous among apes and analogous with, say, theropods. There's no conflict in saying that. Just like wings in birds and bats are analogous, but wings are also homologous among birds. I wouldn't describe that as a "continuum".

Comment: I still can't seem to express what exactly my doubt was, but in any case I think I'm clearer now on the topic. Thanks again!